# Can we display data in html table using ng-model in angular,database is firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display my data in table format, it's coming in input fields but not in table why so? How can I solve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Call Details Dashboard </h1>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)] = "selectedLevel" (change)="selected()" >
      <option *ngFor="let post of posts | async" [ngValue]="post">{{post.user}} 
      </option>
    </select>
<table class="TFtable">  
      <tr >   
          <th>Name</th> <th>Duration</th>  <th>Time</th> <th>Type</th>  
      </tr>  

  <tr *ngFor="let post of posts |async" [(ngModel)] = "selectedLevel.user">
    <td>{{ post.callDuration }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.callTime }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.callType }}</td>
  </tr>  
</table>  //require not as per my requirement


<label>Duration:</label>
<input type="type"name="callDuration" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel.callDuration"> //wokring perfect
```

Comment: You are missing `| async` in table.....

Comment: Yeah! thank you. That worked. But I want only that data which is selected by user through dropdown.

Comment: then you need to filter the values you want

Comment: any example of that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: no, not like this :p I want to select the value from dropdown and search that value in database.

Comment: Well then you need to make a firebase query based on what you want to filter. SO isn't really a code writing service, you should provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried and where you are facing issues. Please check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are using input tag to display your data. You need to use table tag. Here you can see the example code for an table.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-table)